# Html text inside select option isn't rendering

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I've rendered html tags within select's options using `select2` just as follow:

```
$('#select2colors').append($('<option>', {
      value: color,
      text: `<i class="fas fa-square" style="color: ${color}; width:100%;"></i>`
}));

$("#select2colors").select2({
   escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
}
```

That returned me something like this:

[image]

**The problem:** Now I'm trying to do the same, the same logic but without the `append()` part. But isn't working, I was looking for a way to do it but I haven't found anything. What I'm doing is this:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="select2colors">
       @foreach($colors as $color)
        <option value="#{{ $color }}">
             {{ htmlentities("<i class='fas fa-square' style='color: #".$color."; width:100%;'></i>") }}
         </option>
      @endforeach
</select>

$("#select2colors").select2({
   escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
}
```

I thought it'd work the same but isn't. The `<i>` is just disappearing isn't being rendered at all. Does anyone know how could I achieve this to get the same as before?

What I get is this, the HTML isn't rendering:

[image]

Comment: why not use append?

Comment: The first way was for my create's view and the second way is for my edit's view and I have the data in that view that's because I use `@foreach` and also I'm working with external js files and I can't send the data to those files.

Comment: what happens when you remove the error suppression?

Comment: It's laravel I have to use it

Comment: ah, that tag was missing.

Comment: it's not `width=100%;` it should be `width:100%;` inside style attribute

Comment: @Mech is not working

Comment: @L.Flor When appending `<i>.....</i>` is a text .. And on second code `<option><i>...</i></option>` `i` here is an html .. So try to find a way to convert `<i>....</i>` to string/text and I think everything will be fine

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing at startup was to put the HTML directly, and I had to convert the HTML to plain text just as @Mohamed-Yousef comment. First I used `htmlentities()` but what I needed is `html_entity_decode()`, explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```